# ListView row ImageView issue

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have a listview row that has Imageview component. In the `getview()` method i'm doing some checks and according to them i change the `imageview` with `setBackgroundResource()` method.

I have a problem when I run there are rows that the `imageview` component contains several images on each other.

is there anything i can do to fix this problem? 
(i change the `BackgroundResource` one time for each row (position).

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: post the getview code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see some code but I think you should use a ViewHolder.

Example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {            


   ViewHolder holder;                       

   if (convertView == null) {                

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);             
    holder = new ViewHolder();                
    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);               
    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);                
    convertView.setTag(holder);            
   } else {                


    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

   }            
   holder.name.setText(myElements.get(id)); 
   holder.icon.setImageBitmap( mIcon1 );

   return convertView;
  }  

static class ViewHolder {            
    TextView name;            
    ImageView icon;        
}
```

If this doesnt help load the images asynchronously.
I would recommend Picasso.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Regards Nils